# Get tags for docker image without organization

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

To get a docker image's tags using the [docker hub api](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags):

```sh
curl -sL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/<org>/<name>/tags
```

I pipe that into `| jq` and extract what I need.

However some images don't have an organization, e.g. [mariadb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb).

I tried all these:

```sh
curl -sL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mariadb/tags
curl -sL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/_/mariadb/tags
curl -sL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mariadb/_/tags
curl -sL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/mariadb/mariadb/tags
```

But those give errors, or this:

> {"count":0,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[]}

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find official docs for this (can you?), but the trick is to use the magic string `library`:

```sh
curl -sL https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/mariadb/tags
```